# How to stop the application for maven projects in eclipse - m2e

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

While starting the application through maven in eclipse it creating java.exe (application) and also javaw.exe. on clicking terminate button in console only javaw.exe is getting stopped, but java.exe (i.e actual application) is not getting stopped. so each time I have to kill that process manually in task manager.

Is there any better way to stop the application completely ?? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is it a `GUI` application? maybe you need to set default behavior on close clicking

Comment: Why are you starting your application through maven (`Run As > Maven Build...` I presume)?

Comment: @ Rugal its not gui application, web services..

Comment: @Parvel Horal Its maven project, so i starting through maven, run configurations maven build.... through cmd also by running maven commands we can start it...

Comment: @user1919581 Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Kaluva no still stoping the application by killing the java process only.

Answer (score 0):

If you start your application with **spring-boot:start**, so you can shutdown it by using **spring-boot:stop**. In this case, you can prepare two run configuration in eclipse : one with goals **spring-boot:start** and the second with goals **spring-boot:stop**.

But if you use **spring-boot:run**, so the only way to shutdown the application is by killing the java process.

To know the difference between **spring-boot:start** and **spring-boot:run**, please check this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131955/whats-the-difference-between-spring-bootrun-and-spring-bootstart).