# What's the difference between spring-boot:run and spring-boot:start

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

What's the difference between `spring-boot:run` and `spring-boot:start`?

I see both them being available as **Maven goals**.

But what's the difference?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/

Comment: From IDE to execute the run/debug of spring application which one to use?

Answer (score 18):

**spring-boot:run**

> **Description**:
>
> Run an executable archive application.

---

**spring-boot:start**

> **Description**:
>
> Start a spring application. Contrary to the run goal, this does not
>   block and allows other goal to operate on the application. This goal
>   is typically used in integration test scenario where the application
>   is started before a test suite and stopped after.

the info is right here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/index.html

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/):

> **spring-boot:run** runs your Spring Boot application.
>
> **spring-boot:start** [..] Start a spring application. Contrary to the run
> goal, this does not block and allows other goal to operate on the
> application. This goal is typically used in integration test scenario
> where the application is started before a test suite and stopped
> after.